# ion-slides click not proper working when slides last index move to first index

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ion-slides

it's work perfect when slides first index to last but when auto loop go to last index to first index click property is not working.

```
 <ion-slides *ngIf="slides != null" autoplay="3000" loop="true" speed="800" >
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides" >
            <img [src]="slide.BannerImage">
            <div class="con-box">
                <h2>{{slide.BannerName}}</h2>
                <br/>
                <button ion-button color="btn" (click)="fnGotoNewArrivalList(slide.CollectionID,slide.BannerName)">Order Now</button>
            </div>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

Comment: i've same this issue.

Comment: @Afrgun we resolved with use of swiper.

Comment: ok. i will try it, Thanks bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jatin devani please try this code..

replace ion-slides in place use swiper

html

```
    <!-- Swiper -->
 <swiper class="swiper-container" [config]="config" #usefulSwiper>
    <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 7</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 8</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 9</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 10</div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <!-- Add Arrows -->
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    </div>
</swiper>
```

index.html

```
 <script src="assets/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

.ts file

```
config:any;

    this.config = {

            paginationClickable: true,
            spaceBetween: 30,
            centeredSlides: true,
            autoplay: 2500,
            autoplayDisableOnInteraction: false,
            initialSlide : 0,
            slidesPerView: 1,
            // paginationType: 'progress',
             // pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            nextButton: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
          };
```

css file

```
html, body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
    }
    body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color:#000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .swiper-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    }
    .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
```